# Store ipv6 address to mongodb and perform range queries

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am using Java, Mongodb and Morphia. I am trying to store IPv6 addresses to mongodb. In my java code I was able to use BigInteger datatype to assign and store it in mongodb but I am getting morphia mapping exceptions when I try to retrieve them. I have done research and found out that BigInteger is not supported. Some links I was referring to were

https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/75

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/Dj5IsztzKxs

https://code.google.com/p/morphia/issues/detail?id=75

I have a collection which should store ranges of Ipv6 address. So a "range" has "from" IPv6 address and a "to" IPv6 address. I should be able to query for a IPv6 address which falls in a range. Any suggestions on implementing this thing.

Comment: You want to use a specialized IPv6 data type; biginteger is a poor choice for this. For example https://github.com/bolcom/com-bol-ip

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a converter similar to [this](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/411#issuecomment-29135730) one.  I'm not entirely sure why [#75](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/75) was closed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am trying to implement this approach. I will keep you posted.

Comment: In the link you provided, the approach is to encode the IPv6 address as a String and decode it into a BigInteger upon retrieval of this IPv6 String address. Since I am storing it as String, I will not be able to perform range queries. Am I thinking right?